# RestTemplate().getForObject giving "is not a valid HTTP URL"

Tags: spring, webservice-client, resttemplate

I have some very basic code to invoke a webservice. Using RestTemplate().getForObject gives me "is not a valid HTTP URL" error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:         [localhost:9080/someApp/testWs/partners/1] is not a valid HTTP URL
at org.springframework.web.util.UriUtils.encodeHttpUrl(UriUtils.java:245)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$HttpUrlTemplate.encodeUri(RestTemplate.java:651)
at org.springframework.web.util.UriTemplate.expand(UriTemplate.java:140)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:400)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(RestTemplate.java:199)
at org.kofc.test.TestTemplate.main(TestTemplate.java:26)
```

Here is the client code:

```
package org.smpkg.test;

import org.smpkg.dvo.Prtnr;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

public class TestTemplate 
{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1130201273334264152L;
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("I am here ....");
        Prtnr partner = new RestTemplate().getForObject("localhost:9080/someApp/testWs/partners/{id}", Prtnr.class, "1");
        System.out.println("partner name is : " + partner.getPrtnrNm());
    }
}
```

The controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/{id}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public Prtnr getPartner(@PathVariable("id") String id){
    ....
    ....
return partner;
    }
```

The servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.0.xsd">

        <mvc:annotation-driven />

        <context:component-scan base-package="org.somepkg.bso" />

        <!-- 
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
            <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
            <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
        </bean>
         -->

        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
            <property name="messageConverters">
                <util:list>
                    <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter"/>
                </util:list>
            </property>
        </bean>

        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
          <property name="mediaTypes">
            <map>
              <entry key="atom" value="application/atom+xml"/>
              <entry key="html" value="text/html"/>
              <entry key="json" value="application/json"/>
            </map>
          </property>
          <property name="viewResolvers">
            <list>
              <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver"/>
              <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
                <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
                <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
              </bean>
            </list>
          </property>
          <property name="defaultViews">
            <list>
              <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView" />
            </list>
          </property>
        </bean>

        <bean id="content" class="com.springsource.samples.rest.SampleContentAtomView"/>
</beans>
```

Accessing the link localhost:9080/someApp/testWs/partners/1> returns the result, but using RestTemplate().getForObject() does not work.

Here is the Prtnr class:

```
public class Prtnr implements Cloneable, java.io.Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 201207021420600052L;
private Integer prtnrId;
private String creatUserId;
private Date creatTs;
private String updtUserId;
private Date updtTs;
private String prtnrNm;
private Integer cncilNum;
private Character prtnrTypCd;
private Set<PrtnrGeoInfo> prtnrGeoInfos = new HashSet<PrtnrGeoInfo>(0);
private Set<PrtnrDtl> prtnrDtls = new HashSet<PrtnrDtl>(0);
private Set<SuplyDtl> suplyDtls = new HashSet<SuplyDtl>(0);
private Set<TrnsprtDtl> trnsprtDtls = new HashSet<TrnsprtDtl>(0);
private Set<PrtnrFacil> prtnrFacils = new HashSet<PrtnrFacil>(0);
private Set<PrtnrHumanResrc> prtnrHumanResrcs = new HashSet<PrtnrHumanResrc>(0);
.....
.....
Getters and setters for these properties
...
}
```

The error I see on the server side is :
        [12/3/12 10:25:57:764 EST] 00000039 ServletWrappe E   SRVE0068E: Uncaught exception thrown in one of the service methods of the servlet:

```
    spitter.    
    Exception thrown : org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError) (through reference chain: 

    org.kofc.dvo.Prtnr["prtnrGeoInfos"]->org.hibernate.collection.PersistentSet[0]->org.kofc.dvo.PrtnrGeoInfo["id"]->

    org.kofc.dvo.PrtnrGeoInfoId["partner"]->
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:164)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:112)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:446)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:150)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:112)
```

The curl of the webservice is :
       Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:579)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.SettableBeanProperty.deserialize(SettableBeanProperty.java:299)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.SettableBeanProperty$MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(SettableBeanProperty.java:414)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:697)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:580)

What am I missing ???

Thanks

Comment: Now I am getting another error :

Comment: add the source of Prtnr class, maybe it will help

Comment: please add the content of the Prtnr.java to the question, what is the output of `curl` from the webservice? please use the **edit** button don't paste the source code in comments